# i am importing mifs in python code but i keep getting error

Tags: python, python-import

i am trying to import mifs in python but i keep getting error "attempted relative import with no parent package"
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
import pandas as pd
import mifs

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-72-94806d64c699>", line 2, in <module>
    import mifs

  File "D:\salman work\project-powerplant\python code\mifs-master\mifs-master\mifs\mifs.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import mi

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package


import mifs
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-73-a03d989d3e36>", line 1, in <module>
    import mifs

  File "D:\salman work\project-powerplant\python code\mifs-master\mifs-master\mifs\mifs.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import mi

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the file name from mifs.py to something else, it will work.